# Decrypt function doesn't work as intended

Tags: c, encryption

I'm taking a course in fundamental encryption/decryption algorithms, and I'm stuck on this one lab assignment.

We're given a C file called `simplecrypt.c` that, when run, takes an input file and encrypts it to an output file (the input remains intact). Our assignment is to write a decrypt function in `simplecrypt.c` as well, so that you can encrypt and decrypt your files, not just encrypt them. And this is where I'm stuck. I don't know if I'm making it too simple or if I took water over my head with this course, but if anyone can shed some light in what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

This is how the encrypt function looks like. I believe it's AES, if I'm not mistaken? Please note that the encryption key has been given to us in plain text:

```
int crypt(unsigned char *key,
             unsigned char *pInputBuf,
             unsigned char *pOutputBuf,
             long nLength)
{
    int nKeyPos = 0;
    long n;
    unsigned char KeyA = 0;

    if((pInputBuf != NULL) && (pOutputBuf != NULL))
    {
        for(n = 0; n < KEY_BUF; n++)
            KeyA ^= key[n];

        nKeyPos = KeyA%KEY_BUF;

        for(n = 0; n < nLength; n++)
        {
            pOutputBuf[n] = pInputBuf[n]^(key[nKeyPos]*KeyA);
            KeyA += pOutputBuf[n];
            nKeyPos = pOutputBuf[n]%KEY_BUF;
        }
        return 0;   // success
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And this is the decrypt that I made:

```
int decrypt(unsigned char *key,
             unsigned char *pInputBuf,
             unsigned char *pOutputBuf,
             long nLength)
{
    int nKeyPos = 0;
    long n;
    unsigned char KeyA = 0;

    if((pInputBuf != NULL) && (pOutputBuf != NULL))
    {
        for(n = 0; n < KEY_BUF; n++)
            KeyA ^= key[n];

        nKeyPos = KeyA%KEY_BUF;

        for(n = 0; n < nLength; n++)
        {
            // This is where I made changes.
            pInputBuf[n] = pOutputBuf[n]^(key[nKeyPos]*KeyA);
            KeyA += pInputBuf[n];
            nKeyPos = pInputBuf[n]%KEY_BUF;
        }
        return 0;   // success
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Basically, all I did was to reverse the `pInputBuf` with `pOutputBuf` and vice versa. Why doesn't this work in practice when it works in theory? As I said, any help that could send me down the right direction would be awesome.

This is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define KEY_BUF 20
#define FNAME_BUF 256


void stripnl(char *str) 
{
    while(strlen(str) && ((str[strlen(str) - 1] == 13) || (str[strlen(str) - 1] == 10))) 
    {
        str[strlen(str) - 1] = 0;
    }
}


long writefile(unsigned char *pOutputBuf, long size) 
{
    FILE *outfile;
    char fname[FNAME_BUF];
    unsigned char *p = pOutputBuf;
    long i=0;

    // Read in the filename
    printf("Enter the name of the output file: ");
    fgets(fname, sizeof(fname), stdin);

    // We need to get rid of the newline char
    stripnl(fname);

    // Open the file. If NULL is returned there was an error, corrected to VS2012 standard
    // if((outfile = fopen(fname, "wb")) == NULL) 
    if((fopen_s(&outfile, fname, "wb")) != 0) 
    {
        printf("Error Opening File.\n");
        return(0);
    }

    // Put characters in outfile
    while( (i < size) && (fputc(*(p++), outfile) != EOF) )
        i++;

    fclose(outfile);  // Close the file
    return i;
}


char* readfile(unsigned char *pInutBuf, long *nLength) 
{
    FILE *infile;
    char fname[FNAME_BUF];
    int ch=0;
    long i;

    // Read in the filename
    printf("Enter the name of the input file: ");
    fgets(fname, sizeof(fname), stdin);

    // We need to get rid of the newline char
    stripnl(fname);

    // Open the file. If anything else than 0 is returned there was an error
    if((fopen_s(&infile, fname, "rb")) != 0) 
    {
        printf("Error Opening File.\n");
        return(0);
    }

    // get file size
    fseek(infile, 0L, SEEK_END);
    *nLength = ftell(infile);
    // rewind
    fseek(infile, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    pInutBuf = (unsigned char *) malloc(*nLength+1);

    // Read in characters and place them in "buffer"
    ch = fgetc(infile);
    for(i=0; (i < *nLength) && (feof(infile) == 0); i++)
    {
        pInutBuf[i] = (unsigned char)ch;
        ch = fgetc(infile);
    }

    // end of buffer
    pInutBuf[i] = '\0';

    fclose(infile);
    return pInutBuf;
}


int crypt(unsigned char *key,
             unsigned char *pInputBuf,
             unsigned char *pOutputBuf,
             long nLength)
{
    int nKeyPos = 0;
    long n;
    unsigned char KeyA = 0;

    if((pInputBuf != NULL) && (pOutputBuf != NULL))
    {
        for(n = 0; n < KEY_BUF; n++)
            KeyA ^= key[n];

        nKeyPos = KeyA%KEY_BUF;

        for(n = 0; n < nLength; n++)
        {
            pOutputBuf[n] = pInputBuf[n]^(key[nKeyPos]*KeyA);
            KeyA += pOutputBuf[n];
            nKeyPos = pOutputBuf[n]%KEY_BUF;
        }
        return 0;   // success
    }
    return 1;
}

int decrypt(unsigned char *key,
     unsigned char *pOutputBuf,
     unsigned char *pInputBuf,
     long nLength)
{
     int nKeyPos = 0;
     long n;
     unsigned char KeyA = 0;

     if ((pInputBuf != NULL) && (pOutputBuf != NULL))
     {
          for (n = 0; n < KEY_BUF; n++)
               KeyA ^= key[n];

          nKeyPos = KeyA%KEY_BUF;

          for (n = 0; n < nLength; n++)
          {
               pInputBuf[n] = pOutputBuf[n] ^ (key[nKeyPos] * KeyA);
               KeyA += pInputBuf[n];
               nKeyPos = pInputBuf[n] % KEY_BUF;
          }
          return 0; // success
     }
     return 1;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // KEY_BUF+1 corrected to VS2012 standard, we never use the last +1 ('\0') uchar
    unsigned char key[KEY_BUF+1]="abcdefghijklmnopqrst";
    unsigned char *pInputBuf=NULL;
    unsigned char *pOutputBuf=NULL;
    long nLength=0, n;

    if((pInputBuf = readfile(pInputBuf, &nLength)) == NULL)
        return 1;

    pOutputBuf = (unsigned char *) malloc(nLength);

    //if(crypt(key, pInputBuf, pOutputBuf, nLength) != 0)
        //return 2;

    if(decrypt(key, pOutputBuf, pInputBuf, nLength) != 0)
        return 2;

    if(writefile(pOutputBuf, nLength) == 0)
        return 3;
/*
    for(n = 0; n < nLength; n++)
        printf("%c", pInputBuf[n]);
    printf("\n");

    for(n = 0; n < nLength; n++)
        printf("%X", pOutputBuf[n]);
    printf("\n");
*/
    // Free up memory
    if(pInputBuf)
        free(pInputBuf);
    if(pOutputBuf)
        free(pOutputBuf);

    getchar(); // pause and wait for key
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Usually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_(computer_programming)), C is _not_ a [scripting language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language).

Comment: Learn to use the debugger would be a good starting point. And use a small string to

Comment: I've tried to use the debugger, but I fail to understand why and where things go wrong. Let alone, how to actually fix it.

Comment: don't know about the algorithm, What I can say you have some problem with wording - under 'decrypt' the function input should go to 'pOutputBuf', and the function output should go to 'pInputBuf'.

Comment: Please state how you called these functions

Comment: I edited the description above to include the full code. Do note that I have not yet made both encrypt and decrypt work at the same time. I only made the `int decrypt` function and changed the code to call that function instead of the `int crypt`.

Comment: You realize that under the code you sent you're sending garbage to the decrypt right?

Comment: I didn't know that. What exactly is it I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: decrypt is exactly the same as crypt. the only difference is that decrypt gets its input in the 'pOutputBuf' variable and sends its output to 'pInputBuf'. Since pOutputBuf was just malloc'ed, it contains either garbage or zeros, depending on your compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `crypt()` you alter KeyA/nKeyPos based of the **encrypted** cipher text.
In `decrypt()` you alter KeyA/nKeyPos based of the **decrypted** plain text.

Try this:

```
int crypt( unsigned char *key,
           const unsigned char *pPlaintext, //input
           unsigned char *pCiphertext,      //output
           long nLength)
{
    ...
    for(n = 0; n < nLength; n++)
    {
        pCiphertext[n] = pPlaintext[n] ^ (key[nKeyPos]*KeyA);
        KeyA += pCiphertext[n];
        nKeyPos = pCiphertext[n] % KEY_BUF;
    }
}

int decrypt( unsigned char *key,
             const unsigned char *pCiphertext, //input
             unsigned char *pPlaintext,        //output
             long nLength)
{
    ...
    for(n = 0; n < nLength; n++)
    {
        pPlaintext[n] = pCiphertext[n] ^ (key[nKeyPos]*KeyA);
        KeyA += pCiphertext[n];
        nKeyPos = pCiphertext[n] % KEY_BUF;
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but doesn't seem like it worked.

Comment: @tobulos1: inbuf / outbuf mixed up when called from main()?

Comment: I'm a dumbass... thank you. I had switched the plaintext with ciphertext in `main()`.